# Processing flutter images with C++ openCV

Tags: c++, flutter, dart, opencv, dart-ffi

I am working on a project, where I want to process my images using C++ OpenCV.

For simplicity's sake, I just want to convert `Uint8List` to `cv::Mat` and back.

Following [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/building-a-flutter-computer-vision-app-using-dart-ffi-opencv-and-tensorflow-part-2-81472b4ac380) tutorial, I managed to make a pipeline that doesn't crash the app. Specifically:

1. I created a function in a `.cpp` that takes the pointer to my `Uint8List`, `rawBytes`, and encodes it as a `.jpg`:

```
    int encodeIm(int h, int w, uchar *rawBytes, uchar **encodedOutput) {
        cv::Mat img = cv::Mat(h, w, CV_8UC3, rawBytes); //CV_8UC3
        vector<uchar> buf;
        cv:imencode(".jpg", img, buf); // save output into buf. Note that Dart Image.memory can process either .png or .jpg, which is why we're doing this encoding
        *encodedOutput = (unsigned char *) malloc(buf.size());
        for (int i=0; i < buf.size(); i++)
            (*encodedOutput)[i] = buf[i];
        return (int) buf.size();
    }
```

2. Then I wrote a function in a `.dart` that calls my c++ `encodeIm(int h, int w, uchar *rawBytes, uchar **encodedOutput)`:

```
   //allocate memory heap for the image
   Pointer<Uint8> imgPtr = malloc.allocate(imgBytes.lengthInBytes);

   //allocate just 8 bytes to store a pointer that will be malloced in C++ that points to our variably sized encoded image
   Pointer<Pointer<Uint8>> encodedImgPtr = malloc.allocate(8);

   //copy the image data into the memory heap we just allocated
   imgPtr.asTypedList(imgBytes.length).setAll(0, imgBytes);

   //c++ image processing
   //image in memory heap -> processing... -> processed image in memory heap
   int encodedImgLen = _encodeIm(height, width, imgPtr, encodedImgPtr);
   //

   //retrieve the image data from the memory heap
   Pointer<Uint8> cppPointer = encodedImgPtr.elementAt(0).value;
   Uint8List encodedImBytes = cppPointer.asTypedList(encodedImgLen);
   //myImg = Image.memory(encodedImBytes);
   return encodedImBytes;
   //free memory heap
   //malloc.free(imgPtr);
   //malloc.free(cppPointer);
   //malloc.free(encodedImgPtr); // always frees 8 bytes
 }
```

3. Then I linked c++ with dart via:

```
final DynamicLibrary nativeLib = Platform.isAndroid
    ? DynamicLibrary.open("libnative_opencv.so")
    : DynamicLibrary.process();

final int Function(int height, int width, Pointer<Uint8> bytes, Pointer<Pointer<Uint8>> encodedOutput) 
_encodeIm = nativeLib
        .lookup<NativeFunction<Int32 Function(Int32 height, Int32 width, 
Pointer<Uint8> bytes, Pointer<Pointer<Uint8>> encodedOutput)>>('encodeIm').asFunction();
```

4. And finally I show the result in Flutter via:

```
Image.memory(...)
```

Now, the pipeline doesn't crash, which means I haven't goofed up memory handling completely, but it doesn't return the original image either, which means I did mess up somewhere.

Original image: 
[image: 1]

Pipeline output: 
[image: 2]

Comment: Where are you getting `imgBytes` from? My bet is it isn't 8 bit unsigned 3 channel.

Comment: @RichardHeap it's an image I load from assets with `(await rootBundle
                          .load('assets/images/tmp.jpeg')).buffer.asUint8List()`

Comment: So if it's a jpeg, why would you try to tell Mat it's 8UC3? `cv::Mat(h, w, CV_8UC3, rawBytes); //CV_8UC3`

Comment: I mean, `rawBytes` parameter and `imgBytes` variable are Uint8List, but this Uint8List I recover from `.jpeg` stored in my assets folder. So I don't understand the problem with using 8UC3, since Uint8List is a list of 8-bit unsigned ints, and my image has 3 channels - RGB

Comment: But jpeg is compressed, and you are essentially telling Mat the data is uncompressed.

Comment: Bless. I passed via `imdecode` to get the matrix, and it works. Was this your idea all along or is there a better way? Also, would you like to post an answer for that sweet-sweet karma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Richard Heap's guidance in the comments, I managed to fix the pipeline by changing my matrix definition from

```
cv::Mat img = cv::Mat(h, w, CV_8UC3, rawBytes);
```

to

```
vector<uint8_t> buffer(rawBytes, rawBytes + inBytesCount);
Mat img = imdecode(buffer, IMREAD_COLOR);
```

where `inBytesCount` is the length of `imgBytes`.